# Complement of contractible subset of a sphere

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $A$ be a nice closed subset of the sphere $S^n$; for example, we could ask $A\to S^n$ to be a cofibration. Assume that $A$ is contractible.

> > Is then $S^n - A$ also contractible?

It follows by Alexander duality that it has trivial (reduced) homology. But this is, of course, not enough, as the examples of [wild arcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_arc) show.

Comment: Cofibration is not enough (wild arcs are cofibrations). If you assume that $A$ is a subcomplex, then the complement is contractible though.

Comment: Can you give an argument or a reference for the latter?